# What dev do I use to read a USB keyboard in an embedded Linux system?

Tags: linux, console-application

I've compiled the kernel to support USB HID and keyboard devices. When I plug in the USB keyboard, the kernel recognizes it, and goes so far as to latch/unlatch the NUMLOCK led when I press the same key.

***Is there a `dev` file entry I can create so I can read (`cat /dev/input/...`) data from the USB keyboard?***

I appreciate that I might be looking at scanning codes.

I tested the USB HID with a mouse, although it produces garbage on the console, I know it's connected using information I found [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html).

---

***EDIT-Ignacio***

How can I map the following to a `dev` entry, specifically where do I glean the minor revision number?

```
# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c316 Version=2800
N: Name="Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-at91rm9200-1.1/input0
H: Handlers=kbd
B: EV=120003
B: KEY=10000 7 ff800000 7ff febeffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c316 Version=2800
N: Name="Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-at91rm9200-1.1/input1
H: Handlers=kbd
B: EV=3
B: KEY=9f01 400 40000 401878 d800d508 1e0000 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've scanned `/proc/bus/input/devices` for the appropriate event device you can use `MAKEDEV` to create it (character, major number 13, minor number 64+) and [access it as usual](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429).

Comment: Thanks, for responding, but I've got a follow on questions that I can't adequately format in this comment.  (See EDIT-Igancio.)

Comment: I've actually tried every minor device number above 64:  
`for (( i=64; i<=255; i++)) do; mknod /dev/input/test-$i c 13 $i && cat test-$i`  
and for each iteration through the loop I get:  
`cat: /dev/input/test: No such device`

Comment: Looks like your kernel doesn't have event support. You'll need to build and insert the module or rebuild the kernel.

Comment: Event support? I had no idea that it could actually be disabled in the kernel?  Where do I find that option? (and why would the mouse still work?)

Comment: If you're referring to the `CONFIG_EPOLL` option, it is set to `"yes"` (in  "general/configure for small systems").